# How to Create RSS to Twitter using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, twitter, rss, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to build a sample project to digest an RSS feed using Azure's available Logic Apps to gather articles as they occur and then tweet the articles. I am focused on using [Yahoo! Finance](https://developer.yahoo.com/finance/company.html) RSS feeds to pull in 3 company tickers; MSFT, AAPL, and GOOG. From what I've discovered reading the documentation about Logic apps on the Azure website, should I be using an HTTP connector to retrieve the RSS feed, then a Twitter connector to tweet the feed. The documentation is sparse and I am very new. How might I be able to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

We right now don't have a native RSS Connector, but we did just add an RSS Api App to our GitHub here: https://github.com/logicappsio/RSSApi

You could try with the HTTP Action, but may be difficult to parse the RSS within the app since the format of RSS is tricky.

You could deploy that RSS API app in your resource group, and use it to retrieve items.  Let me know if that connector meets your needs, and what changes it would need to accomplish this.